# JSP pages caching informations from old session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem that's when I connect with two differents users using servlet and JSP , infromations of the first user keeps shown when I connect with any other user even I invalidate session when the connected user logout and I'm using 
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />`
in all JSP pages , any other ideas please ? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

you can copy and paste this code in every page of your site which clears the cached page.

```
<%response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);

if(session.getAttribute("some_token")==null)
 response.sendRedirect("login/login.html");
%>
```

In logout you must be invalidating session so when you click back it would check the some_token attribute value in session and if not there it will redirect you to login page . But remember after login you are setting some_token attribute in session.

Comment: thanx AMal , but that's not my problem , I'm invalidating session , my problem is when I connect with another user , old informations keeps shown until I do ctrl+F5

Comment: I had this similar problem.But this worked fine for me.Because the cache is being cleared,the page will reload normally,from begining.If the session is invalidated,then the details of the previous user saved in session will also be gone.

Comment: @Hamdi:please make sure,you have checked this in all jsp pages.

Comment: Yes.It is different from your previous one right.Please put these code in `scriplets`.Thanks